# Laravel Eloquent Subquery Using 3 Tables

Tags: eloquent

The goal of this query is to find all Stories which have an Image Type with a name of "email_small" associated with them. Not all stories have images.

There are three tables/models involved: Storys, StoryImage, and ImageTypes

A story can have many story images

```
/* Story model */
public function storyImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StoryImage::class);
}
```

While a story image has one image type

```
/* Storyimage model */
public function imgtype()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Imagetype','imagetype_id');
}
```

I can get to the second step of selecting all stories with an image, but I'm lost within the subquery

```
$stories  = Story::whereHas('storyImages', function($query){
               $query->where($query->imgtype()->name, '=', 'email_small');
            })
            ->->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use two queries? First select ID of imgType with name "email_small" and then check that ID:

```
$id = Imagetype::where('name', 'email_small')->first()->id;
$stories = Story::whereHas('storyImages', function($q) use ($id) {
    $q->where('imagetype_id', $id);
})->get();
```

I'm sure that even if you write everything in one function Laravel will still call few queries.

Comment: Ah right, that's probably simpler. I was way overthinking that one.